# Can I share an unpublished paper without this counting as prior publication?

Tags: publications, publishability, preprint

I need to share a draft of a scientific paper with another person. I have the intention of publish it, but it is not ready for submission yet.
When submitting my paper, I would like to avoid accusations that it is not original work.
Do I have to take anything into account in this respect before sending it?

Comment: Do you have any particular concern why you should not just email the paper to your colleague?

Comment: More than a colleague, he is a person interested in the work.

Comment: I answered with "use dropbox", and you commented that you don't want to know the best way to share the paper, but rather the "legal consequences" of doing so. Since this differs from the title of your question, and both the title and your comment differ from the question in the last line, I've deleted my answer and flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking". Please edit it to make it explicit exactly what you'd like to know.

Comment: @siserte and what's the concern?

Comment: @henning it is an unveiled work that I expect to publish I would not like to read any subsequent review  saying that it is a non original work.

Comment: @Pont I hope it will be better now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comment, your main concern is that your sharing the draft may count as prior publication and will prevent you from eventually publishing the final paper.

**Sharing a draft does not count as publication.**

Moreover, your draft is most likely going to change a lot before you submit the final manuscript to a journal for review. In general, it is a good idea to share drafts early and often, so you can collect as much feedback as possible.

Some precautions:

- make the draft status explicit
- ensure the paper can't be found online before acceptance, so as not to compromise blind review (may depend on the field)
- ask that the draft paper not be cited or circulated without permission

Comment: *ensure the paper can't be found online* – This is not a sound advice for fields with an active preprint culture, such as those fields using the Arxiv.

Comment: @Wrzprmft maybe like this? I've had a paper rejected, because a draft with my name was online.